# Selecting Three js object from transparent menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a building model in Three js. For my use case, I select a component from the building model and capture the `uuid` of the component. Then I need to click a button from the menu to see detailed information. Menu is inserted to the page in scripts.
When I click the button it selects the component of building which stays behind it. Therefore, I cannot access the data which I selected before. [image]

In the above picture for example, I have Buttons1-3. Before going to buttons, I select one component of building model. Then when I click any of the button, mouse also selects the building component behind it such as window behind Button1, wall behind Button2, etc. Therefore, I cannot access the `uuid` of component which I selected before. How can I prevent this?? Following is the code:

```
    JA.addMenu = function () {

    JA.menu = JA.container.appendChild( document.createElement( 'div' ) );
    JA.menu.id = 'movable';
    JA.menu.title = 'Move the menu around or click here to close the menu';
    JA.menu.addEventListener( 'mousedown', JA.mouseMove, false );
    JA.menu.innerHTML = '<a id=closerIcon href=JavaScript:JA.toggleMenu(); ><p><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></p></a>' +
        '<p>' +
            '<a href="" title=' + JA.TitleText2 + '>' + JA.TitleText1 + '' + JA.TitleText1 + '</a> ' +
        '</p>' +
        '<hr>' +
    '';
    window.addEventListener( 'mouseup', JA.mouseUp, false);

};

JA.Button1Tab = function () {

    var tab = JA.menu.appendChild( document.createElement( 'div' ) );
    tab.title = 'Button1';
    tab.innerHTML =
        '<a href=# onclick=JA.toggleDialogs(JA.aboutDialog); ><p class=button >' +
            '<i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i> Button1' +
        '</p></a>';
    JA.aboutDialog = JA.container.appendChild( document.createElement( 'div' ) );
    JA.aboutDialog.style.cssText = 'display: none; background-color: #ccc; left: 50px; opacity: 0.9; padding: 20px; ' +
        'bottom: 0; left: 0; height: 370px; margin: auto; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; width: 500px; z-index:10; ';
    JA.aboutDialog.innerHTML =
        '<h3>' + document.title + ' ' + JA.titleIcon + '</h3>' +
        +'<h4>Menu explains the following:</h4>' 
    '';
};
```

Comment: so every interactive action is working (e.g. rotate,select,pan or what else) ignoring the menu at the front?

Comment: All interactive actions work properly in Three js. It does not ignore the menu. The functions defined for the buttons work well. For my use-case, I walk in the building model and select one component in the model. Then I click the button. But then it selects the building component which is behind the button and after runs the function I defined for the button

Comment: aha. so the container and the menu are both working..well a first approach is to seperate the clicks (e.g. right click for selecting object and left for the menu) , a second approach is to dissable the container as long as the menu is visible. Tell me if i get it right or you want something else.

Comment: Allright, thanks. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Also have you tried setting the z-index of the menu ? As i see you set the buttons z-index and not the menu panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so, in your code you have set the z-index of the menu buttons. Try setting the z-index of the menu panel so the container will be below the menu. The menu and the container in your code are on the same level thats why both listen the click event.